# Error while uploading large files in RoR from different networks

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, carrierwave

I am working on a RoR website and i upload media files (like mp3,pdf,images and video) on the website. Website is hosted on AWS and i am using S3 bucket to upload the media files. When i upload media files on S3 bucket it's uploaded successfully from my network but when we try to upload the media files from other networks it stops the uploading after 4 to 5%.

I also increase the session timeout and set it 30 minute but still i am facing the same problem from other network.

Am i missing something in the code? Is this something network security can block or it is in my code? I am very confused and i can successfully upload media files in bulk from one network and it always stop from the other. I suppose it is related to network settings and firewalls but i am not sure.

Any idea or help in this will be highly appreciated.

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0):

Are you using unicorn? The [default timeout](http://unicorn.bogomips.org/Unicorn/Configurator.html#method-i-timeout) is 30 seconds.

Are you using heroku? They limit connections to [55 seconds](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/limits#router).

Otherwise you may need to provide more information about your application server/implementation/etc.

For more about dealing with file uploads in rails: [RoR - Large file uploads in rails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18342385/ror-large-file-uploads-in-rails),
[Best Ruby on Rails Architecture for Image Heavy App](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16307493/best-ruby-on-rails-architecture-for-image-heavy-app/16341162#16341162)